# why dummy value after vector opertor+?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword

I implementing vector. so i test operators, but operator+ is not working correctly.

hereis header MyDoubleVector.h

```
class MyDoubleVector {
public:
    MyDoubleVector();

    MyDoubleVector(size_t init_capacity);

    MyDoubleVector(const MyDoubleVector& v);

    ~MyDoubleVector();

    MyDoubleVector& operator=(const MyDoubleVector& v); //for deep copy

    bool operator==(const MyDoubleVector& v); //binary

    MyDoubleVector& operator+=(const MyDoubleVector& add);

    MyDoubleVector operator[](int index); //return reference to data that requested index

    MyDoubleVector operator+(const MyDoubleVector& rhs); //binary

    MyDoubleVector operator-(const MyDoubleVector& rhs); //binary

    MyDoubleVector operator*(const MyDoubleVector& rhs); //binary

    MyDoubleVector operator-(); //unary

    MyDoubleVector operator()(); //unary

    void pop_back();

    void push_back(double x);

    size_t capacity() const; 

    size_t size() const; 

    void reserve(size_t n); 

    bool empty() const; 

    void clear(); 

    void print_info();

private:
    double *data;
    size_t capa;
    size_t used;

};
```

and here is implement code "MyDoubleVector.cpp"

```
MyDoubleVector MyDoubleVector::operator+(const MyDoubleVector &rhs) { //binary
//pre : same size, 
//poset : return sum,
  if (capa != rhs.capa) {
      exit(1);
  }
  MyDoubleVector tmp(capa);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < capa; i++) {
      tmp.data[i] = data[i] + rhs.data[i];
  }
  return tmp;
};
```

and main code is

```
int i = 0;

MyDoubleVector v1(3);
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    v1.push_back(i);
}
cout << "v1" << endl;
v1.print_info();

MyDoubleVector v2(3);
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    v2.push_back(i * 10);
}
cout << "v2" << endl;
v2.print_info();

cout << "(v1+v2)" << endl;
(v1+v2).print_info();
```

output is

v1

0 1 2 3

used : 4, capa : 4

v2

0 10 20 30

used : 4, capa : 4

(v1+v2)

-6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66

used : 0, capa : 4

i think retruned tmp is freed when print_info() function executed.

how print vector correctly?

Comment: Are you sure your copy-constructor is working as it is supposed to? Does it do a *deep* copy?

Comment: You need to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I also recommend you take some time to read [the canonical implementation of binary arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators). In your case it's recommended that the `operator+` function is a non-member function, implemented using the member-function `operator+=`.

Comment: Sorry, it's homework, and must use member method..TT

Comment: [OT]: missing some `const` for the method.

Comment: [OT2]: You should not use exit() in a library (well, your class looks like it *could* reside in one, at least), rather throw an exception!

Comment: [OT3]: Wouldn't you rather want the vectors have same *size* instead of *capacity*?

Comment: One last thing: While your `operator+` (and your `operator+=` I assume) may make some sense in a way, it doesn't make sense from a *container* perspective, where a `+` operator typically *appends* two containers. Your class is more a reimplementation of [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) than [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: everybody thanks to advice. i fix the bug. it's that print_info() method is print value by capa (not used, i fix capa to used). and operator+  don't copy used, so (v1+v2).used = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting the `used` of the return vector. Without seeing the rest of the implementation of the class, I guess you can change to:

```
MyDoubleVector MyDoubleVector::operator+(const MyDoubleVector &rhs) { //binary
//pre : same size, 
//poset : return sum,
  if (capa != rhs.capa) {
      exit(1);
  }
  MyDoubleVector tmp(capa);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < capa; i++) {
      tmp.push_back(data[i] + rhs.data[i]);
  }
  return tmp;
};
```

Comment: thansk for comment! i noticed that "Does it do a deep copy?". i missed the used copy...TT i fixed the bug, thank you!